# Run another task from a task in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to run task from another task?

For example I have two tasks: one print "Hello", another print "World":

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "printHello",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo Hello",
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "taskName": "printWorld",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo World",
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "taskName": "printHelloWorld",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "...",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I added third tasks `printHelloWorld` which should first call task `printHello` and then `printWorld`.

Is it possible?

Comment: The `dependsOn` property is close to what you want. The issue is it runs each in parallel in its own terminal. If that is actually what you want, than I would suggest you use it!